# Keep getting database not open error

Tags: android, database, sqlite

So I'm fine tuning my sqlclass.class file and trying to use the onCreate methods, but my app keeps crashing with the following error in logcat saying "database not open".

This is what is on my main class that starts the app:

```
package com.anthony.myApp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

public class appMain extends Activity implements OnClickListener{
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        View newData = findViewById(R.id.mainMenu_newBtn);
        newData.setOnClickListener(this);
        View continueBtn = findViewById(R.id.mainMenu_continueBtn);
        continueBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
        View exitBtn = findViewById(R.id.mainMenu_exitBtn);
        exitBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
        View btnRegister = findViewById(R.id.mainMenu_register);
        btnRegister.setOnClickListener(this);
        Log.d("MYTAG", "Loaded");

        sqlclass helper2 = new sqlclass(this);
        SQLiteDatabase db = helper2.getWritableDatabase();         

    }
    @Override
    public void onWindowFocusChanged (boolean hasFocus)
    {

    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v){
        Log.d("MYTAG", "Switch");
        switch(v.getId()){
        case R.id.mainMenu_newBtn:
            Log.d("MYTAG", "New Button");
            Intent in = new Intent(this, createNewBook.class);
            startActivity(in);
            break;
        case R.id.mainMenu_continueBtn:
            Intent ic= new Intent(this, continueData.class);
            startActivity(ic);
            break;
        case R.id.mainMenu_register:
            Intent register = new Intent(this, loginSettings.class);
            startActivity(register);
            break;
        case R.id.mainMenu_exitBtn:
            finish();
            break;

        }
    }
}
```

This is what is on my sqlclass onCreate:

L

```
og.d("MYTAG", "onCreate");
        try{
            String sql = "CREATE TABLE if not exists _Data (" + _ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, _tableName TEXT NOT NULL, _isFavorites TEXT NOT NULL, _cdgDiscs TEXT NOT NULL, _binderNumber TEXT NOT NULL, _discNumber TEXT NOT NULL, _discStatus TEXT NOT NULL, _discNotes TEXT NOT NULL, _mp3g TEXT NOT NULL, _mp3Path TEXT NOT NULL);";
            db.execSQL(sql);
            String sql2 = "CREATE TABLE if not exists _artistNames (" + _ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, Initials TEXT NOT NULL, Artist TEXT NOT NULL);";
            db.execSQL(sql2);
            String sql3 = "CREATE TABLE if not exists _genres (" + _ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, genre TEXT NOT NULL);";
            db.execSQL(sql3);
            String sql4 = "CREATE TABLE if not exists _artistInitials (" + _ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, Initials TEXT NOT NULL);";
            db.execSQL(sql4);
            String sql5 = "CREATE TABLE if not exists _songInitials (" + _ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, bookName TEXT NOT NULL, initials TEXT NOT NULL);";
            db.execSQL(sql5);
            String sql6 = "CREATE TABLE if not exists _cdProperties ("+_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, tableName TEXT NOT NULL, created TEXT NOT NULL, edited TEXT NOT NULL, discStatus TEXT NOT NULL, discNotes TEXT NOT NULL, discModel TEXT NOT NULL, discName TEXT NOT NULL, binderNumber TEXT NOT NULL, binderPageNumber TEXT NOT NULL, discNumber TEXT NOT NULL, cdID TEXT NOT NULL);";
            db.execSQL(sql6);

            Log.d("MYTAG", "New data table created");
            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            ArrayList<String> genres = new ArrayList<String>();
            BufferedReader br = null;
             try{
                br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(contextHelper.getAssets().open("genres.csv")));
                String word;

                    while((word=br.readLine())!= null){
                        genres.add(word);
                    }


                }catch(Exception e){
                    Log.d("MYTAG", "E="+e);
                }
                finally {
                    try {
                        br.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            for(int i=0; i<genres.size(); i++){
                values.clear();
                values.put("genre", genres.get(i).toString());
                db.insertOrThrow("_genres", null, values);
            }

            Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT genre FROM _genres ORDER BY genre COLLATE NOCASE", null);
            if(cursor!=null){
                if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
                    do{
                        Log.d("MYTAG", "Genre="+cursor.getString(0));
                    } while (cursor.moveToNext());
                }
            }


        }catch (SQLiteException e){
            Log.d("MYTAG", "newAppSetup e="+e);
        }finally{
            if(db.isOpen()){
                db.close();
            }
        }
    }
```

Here's the error:

```
07-01 17:41:10.833: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(18629): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.anthony.myApp/com.anthony.myApp.appMain}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: database not open
07-01 17:41:10.833: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(18629):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
07-01 17:41:10.833: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(18629):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
07-01 17:41:10.833: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(18629):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
07-01 17:41:10.833: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(18629):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
07-01 17:41:10.833: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(18629):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-01 17:41:10.833: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(18629):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
07-01 17:41:10.833: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(18629):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
07-01 17:41:10.833: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(18629):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-01 17:41:10.833: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(18629):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
07-01 17:41:10.833: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(18629):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
07-01 17:41:10.833: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(18629):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
07-01 17:41:10.833: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(18629):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-01 17:41:10.833: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(18629): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: database not open
07-01 17:41:10.833: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(18629):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.endTransaction(SQLiteDatabase.java:552)
07-01 17:41:10.833: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(18629):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:113)
07-01 17:41:10.833: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(18629):     at com.anthony.myApp.appMain.onCreate(appMain.java:38)
07-01 17:41:10.833: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(18629):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
07-01 17:41:10.833: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(18629):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
07-01 17:41:10.833: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(18629):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: Could you please include the code that actually opens the database (i.e., calls getWritableDatabase)?

Comment: Ya, I forgot about that, I edited my post.  helper.getWritableDatabase();  --edit-- i just clipped my entire main class.

Comment: Well, it's still not clear how those two code snippets interact.

Comment: Well, the 2nd snippet is the sqlclass.class... am I missing something that should be calling the onCreate or onUpgrade?

Answer (score 4):

Don't close your DB in the `finally` block...

```
finally {
    if (db.isOpen()) {
        db.close(); // <== DON'T DO THIS
    }
}
```

Comment: ..oh! I think that did it, do those overridden method automatically close it for you in either onCreate or onUpgrade?

Comment: @Anthony: I still don't fully understand the SQLite side of things in Android but I do know to generally just leave the 'system' to handle everything. I never deliberately close a DB using `db.close()` and haven't had any problems so far. I do know that I did exactly what you did in a `finally` block when first using SQLite in Android and had similar problems. I think it comes down to the way `SQLiteOpenHelper` and SQLite in Android itself actually work. Normally I would close a DB when coding on a PC but it doesn't work the same with Android.

Comment: YUP! This was the problem! Thank you so much, I do have one other question abou the onUpgrade method. What if the user skipped a version and upgraded on the next. Would i have to design the onUpgrade to accomodate all the changes?

Comment: thanks for the notes. Weird that you said that, because all my other methods in the sqlclass I had to close the DB because my app would force close stating that the database wasn't closed...

Comment: @Anthony: I generally use 'transactions' which are heavy but possibly mean things work differently. As for skipping a version upgrade, make sure all upgrades are incremental, add tables and/or columns but leave obsolete tables/columns in place....that's the simple approach. Ideally, you would really need to 'export' everything to a temp DB and then re-import based on previous version vs new version. It's a tricky business but that's unfortunately how DB upgrades have to work.

Answer (score 0):

remove

```
 db.close();
```

you are closing all the db connection and you might be using it somewhere else , thats you your application gets crashed.
Thanks